# How to detect double click in Windows Store apps?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, mouseevent, double-click

In C++ Windows Store apps, there is an event on the main window called **PointerPressed**. I'm trying to find how to detect double click as opposed to single click. I don't see an equivalent event to **PointerPressed** that would trigger upon mouse double click.

I also checked the **PointerPressed** event arguments and it doesn't seems to contain information about whether or not it is a single or double click.

Its easy to perform it using the **DoubleTapped** property on the **GestureRecognizer**, but what if I don't use the gesture recognizer? Is there no way to detect a simple mouse double-click???

Thank you.

Edit: Its a pure C++ Direct3D application targetted for the Windows Store, not using XAML or any user interface thing like that.

Comment: I'm confused, you say "there is an easy way to do it with GestureRecognizer", then say, "If I don't use that, there is no easy way". Well, yeah. That's what happens when you arbitrarily decide not use to things. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, I was just pointing out that the GestureRecognizer has this functionality, while the basic windows don't have it.

Comment: Why is the CoreWindow class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.core.corewindow.aspx) doesn't have an event for DoubleTapped, just like UIElement or the GestureRecognizer? In other words, what's the proper way to achieve this for mouse double clicks?

Comment: The only work-around I've found so far is to use the Pointer.Timestamp property, and check if the time since last mouse press event received is less than the system double click time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the Pointer.Timestamp property, and check if the time since last mouse press event received is less or equal than you double-click time.

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
static unsigned long long LastTimestamp = 0;
static unsigned long long DoubleClickTimeMS = 250;
if( event == mouse_down )
{
    if( (Pointer->Timestamp - LastTimestamp) / 1000 <= DoubleClickTimeMS )
    {
        //switch event for a double-click
        event = double_click;
    }
    LastTimestamp = Pointer->Timestamp;
}
```

Comment: In case you want to support a single click (usually you do if you decide to add double click event too), you may also want to have a timer where you'd raise the single click event of no second click occurred within the time given.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `DoubleTapped` event on a `UIElement`. No need to use a `GestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Yeah but how to get it if I click in an empty window, such as one that contains a DirectX context?

Comment: I think you should still get it on a `SwapChainPanel`, is that not the case?

Comment: I'm not developing my application in XAML. It is a pure Direct3D app for Windows Store, so it doesn't use a _panel_.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bad answer as it doesn't answer the question but, conceptually, a click is an event. A doubleclick consists of two clicks which are, respectively, two events. Since a gesture consists of multiple such events, we see that a doubleclick is actually a gesture. Hence, you probably should use the gesture recognizer.

Comment: So basically you are suggesting that even if I only support a mouse, that I should be using the gesture recognizer regardless?